# Changing column names in Julia to strings

Tags: dataframe, julia

this might seem like a silly question. Started with Julia very recently and encountered this trivial problem.

Creating matrix as follows:

```
Matice = rand(10, 10)
Matice = convert(DataFrame, Matice)
```

Wanted to change the column names to A,B,C,...

```
NewColNames = Array(String,ncol(Matice))
for i = 1:(ncol(Matice))
    NewColNames[i] = string('A' + (i-1))
end

names!(Matice, NewColNames)
```

the last line produces an error.
Also tried to do something more direct, such as:

```
for i = 1:(ncol(Matice))
    names(Matice)[i] = string('A' + (i-1))
end
```

But it isn't working again.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `names!(Matice, Symbol.(NewColNames))` - the column names need to be symbols (this is what the error message said)

Comment: Indeed! Thanks a lot and Merry Christmas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought it is worth to add three remarks:

1) Probably the simplest code to generate the symbols you want is

```
Symbol.('A':'A'+ncol-1)`
```

where `ncol` is number of columns you want.

2) Currently you can create `DataFrame` from vector of vectors and give names for variables in the constructor, e.g.:

```
DataFrame([rand(10) for i in 1:10], Symbol.('A':'J'))
```

3) when [this PR to DataFrames](https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl/pull/1325) is merged and released (probably in a few weeks at most) you will be able to write the same using a matrix:

```
DataFrame(rand(10, 10), Symbol.('A':'J'))
```

Answer (score 0):

With help of Dan, posting an alternative solution without creating a NewColNames vector:

```
names!(Matice, [Symbol('A' + (i-1)) for i in 1:(ncol(Matice))])
```